# ATL and types from scrrun.dll

Tags: c++, com, midl

I have interface in ATL project which must contains member with parameter of Scripting::IDictionary** but in MIDL file with description of my interface it's not possible because Scripting library is not presented in default library. I always have scrrun.tlb and trying to use it in MIDL but it's not work

Code is here: [midl-code](http://qqwcuq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pmBH-kojLegl3HinNBukxxNqfNEuL7xJlAEJYc2pcBiLpqp2wzfjvM3s-ZnUgp3hL7hYCi_f4cnOUHEIJW40nBaDJOf956U5M/Capture.PNG)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your IDL:

`importlib("scrrun.dll");`

Then you can use `IDictionary`.

Works for me on XP and up.

Here is a snippet of some of my IDL:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

library FooLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    importlib("scrrun.dll");

    [
        uuid(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX),
        helpstring("_FooLibEvents Interface")
    ]
    dispinterface _IFooEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
        [id(1)] void AnEvent(IDictionary* dict);
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying but but get

error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "IDictionary"

error MIDL2026: cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation.

Would You show me working code?

Comment: Does it work?  I can create a new ATL project form scratch if that helps.

Comment: Ahhh.  Sadly I cannot help you with VS2010.